# How to get instance of the derived class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

I have two classes that inherits from a base class and in this base class, I would like to retrieve the instance that was made.

```
C* A::getCinstance()
{
    return dynamic_cast<C*>(this);
}
```

and i have this error

```
erreur: cannot dynamic_cast ‘this’ (of type ‘class A* const’) to type ‘struct C*’ (target is not pointer or reference to complete type)
```

I am researching but I did not find anything on the internet.

I thanks you in advance, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Did you include the file that declares class C?

Comment: I'm curious why you'd want to do this. Seems like you'd just want to do `dynamic_cast<C*>(pointerToAObject)` wherever you are calling this from.

Comment: Looks like bad design, why do you not use virtual functions to model an interface?

Answer (score 0):

Typical use of `dynamic_cast` is when casting to a derived class from a base class instance. For example, when class `C` has class `A` as a base class. (There are, however, other situations for which dynamic_cast may be used, but I do not think that discussion would help you at this point.) This compiler error is telling you that you do not have a situation for which `dynamic_cast` may be used. In fact, the error says "‘struct C*’ (target is not pointer or reference to complete type)", which means it does not even know what `C` is. For more help, you will need to provide a more complete example.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` can be used for cross-casting as well. And `struct C` is known from the compiler, but is not fully declared.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You are correct! I do not think discussing cross-casting will help clarify things for the original question. I will, however, relax the statement in my answer, and since I am not that familiar with cross-casting, I will have to add that to the long list of corners of C++ that I have not yet studied!